# How to quickly create a hyperlink to a sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a contents page of all the sheets in the document.
All of the cells listed under 'Rounds' and 'Data Input' have the same name as the sheet they are linking to, as you can see in the screenshot.

[image]
[image]

I was wondering if there is a way to create a link for all of these cells automatically, instead of going through every single one.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C0xHopvL6_lYTbGQsCOjO0b7tk61nBYWQqc2_IH_xXc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by recording a Macro. Here are the steps I did whilst recording.

1. Delete all contents in the cells.
2. Paste in the array formula @player0 made me, into the first cell under the 'Rounds' column.

[image]

3. Select all the cells in the column and click on 'Convert to Links'.

[image]

4. Set colour to blue and underline so it looks like a link.

Here's the finished macro.

[image]